# Execution order of script tags

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The script async attribute</h1>

<p id="p1">Hello World!</p>
<script>alert("execute this second")</script>
<script async>alert("execute this first");</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why `script` tags are executed in order even after using `async` keyword. Any help ?

Comment: you can using Promise

Comment: Is the example right? Why would async make it run _earlier_?

Comment: No, the example is not entirely correct. The async attribute does not necessarily make the script run earlier than other scripts.

Comment: any possibilities ?

Comment: ["_the classic script will be fetched in parallel to parsing and evaluated as soon as it is available_"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attributes). Obviously an inline script is available immediately. I suppose the attribute is purposed to be used with external scripts only (like `defer`).

Comment: "Scripts without async, defer or type="module" attributes, as well as inline scripts without the type="module" attribute, are fetched and executed immediately before the browser continues to parse the page." from docs :/

Comment: Yes, and that's what happens in your code. Adding `async` attribute to a script element doesn't change the order HTML elements are parsed.

Comment: Also async doesn't mean an external script must load later. Especially if the browser has a cached version of the file the execution might be in a different order but they don't have to be in a different order.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extract of the [HTML specification on `async`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-async):

> Classic scripts may specify ... `async`, but must not specify [it]
> unless the `src` attribute is present. Module scripts may specify
> the `async` attribute (...).

In other words: Since `async` is disallowed without `src` (for your type of scripts), it is effectively ignored.

That means, both scripts will run synchronously.

Comment: Nice catch from the specs. I expected to see this in MDN docs too, but it was mentioned only in the context of `defer` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the function is async but it will always start after the code above it has started, you can make it so that the above code starts after some delay like so:-

```html
<script>
  setTimeout(()=>{
    alert("this will be executed after")
  },1000)
</script>
<script async>
  alert("this will be executed first")
</script>
```

you can also wrap the code in a function and call it after the async function is executed.

Comment: so no need async then..it works without async too... i need without script modification by the way :/ but thanks